# How can I configure one button to open/close all accordions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, accordion

I have a component that creates a collapsible accordion, using the following code:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const Collapsible = (props) =>{
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const toggle = () => {
        setOpen(!open);
    }
    return(
        <div>
            <button className={props.level} onClick={toggle}>{props.label}</button>
            {open && (
                <div className="toggle">
                    {props.children}
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Collapsible;
```

I use this in multiple places in my main app, sometimes using accordions within other accordions. In multiple instances, I don't actually know how many accordions will be on the page, because they are dynamically rendered based on the data. With this in mind, I want to create a button in the main app that would open (and another that would close) all accordions, without having a set number in mind, and without rendering them all in the main app (i.e. some accordions are rendered in other components, that are then imported into the main app).

I've tried using ref hooks to accomplish this:

1. Added ref in the Collapsible component's button, accessed from parent through props:

```
 <button className={props.level} onClick={toggle} ref={props.innerRef}>{props.label}</button>
```

2. Adding the following ref in the main app:

```
const childRef = useRef();
const openClick = () => {
   childRef.state = true;
}

const closeClick = () => {
   childRef.state = false;
}
```

3. Using the following buttons in the main app:

```
<button onClick = {openClick}>
   Expand all
</button>
<button onClick = {closeClick}>
   Collapse all
</button>
```

4. Adding the ref to the accordion when rendering:

```
<Collapsible label="" level="content" innerRef={childRef}>
```

This does absolutely nothing, likely because you can't access state in the way I'm attempting in #2, but I thought it was worth a shot...

Any thoughts on whether this is doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty common to have a more-or-less arbitrary collection of component instances that need some coordination. An approach that I have had success with is to create a [Context](https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context) with an associated hook that components can use to register. The hook returns a view of the shared state and functions to modify that state, subject to your needs.

Here, you could create a Context that stores the `opener` functions for each of the registered components, and provides `openAll`/`closeAll` functions:

```js
const AccordionProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [openers] = useState(new Set());

  // Should new collapsibles spring open when created?
  // (necessary to support recursive opening)
  const [defaultOpen, setDefaultOpen] = useState(false);

  const register = useCallback(
    (opener) => {
      openers.add(opener);
      return () => openers.delete(opener); // return a deregister function for `useEffect`
    },
    [openers]
  );

  const openAll  = useCallback(() => {
    setDefaultOpen(true);
    openers.forEach(opener => opener(true)),
  }, [setDefaultOpen, openers]);

  const closeAll = useCallback(() => {
    setDefaultOpen(false);
    openers.forEach(opener => opener(false)),
  }, [setDefaultOpen, openers]);

  return (
    <AccordionContext.Provider
      value={{ register, openAll, closeAll, defaultOpen }}
      children={children}
    />
  );
};
```

... and a hook called by each child that registers with the context, and returns your familiar `toggle`/`open` values:

```js
const useAccordionAsClient = () => {
  const { register, defaultOpen } = useContext(AccordionContext);

  const [open, opener] = useState(defaultOpen);
  const toggle = useCallback(() => opener((open) => !open), [opener]);

  useEffect(() => register(opener), [register, opener]);

  return { toggle, open };
};
```

It's also handy to have a separate hook for the actions that you can execute en masse:

```js
const useAccordionAsManager = () => {
  const { openAll, closeAll } = useContext(AccordionContext);

  return { openAll, closeAll };
};
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-maria-j718d0?file=/src/App.js)

Note that for simplicity this is just using the individual `opener` (aka `setOpen`) functions as unique identifiers for each registered component.  A flexible alternative would be use some other identifier, so you could open/close arbitrary accordions on navigation etc.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response - taking some time to wrap my head around it. I've tried it out and it works for my first level of accordions but not the second level. The main difference I see is that I have accordions within accordions, which would be something like the following in your example: <Collapsible label="1"><NestedCollapsibles /></Collapsible>

Comment: @ArcPie_22 All `Collapsible` components within a single `AccordionProvider` are managed together in the sample code. If there were a set of `Collapsible`s that needed to be controlled separately then you'd make a separate Context. Does that help?

Comment: Could that separate context then be controlled by the same buttons? I'm about to try it either way in the hopes that it does...

Comment: Perhaps I could be little clearer – if you just need one button to control ALL the `Collapsible` components then you can put one single shared `AccordionProvider` arbitrarily far up your component hierarchy (even right at the top!) – it doesn't have to be near the `Collapsible` components themselves, just as long as they're somewhere within the context.

Comment: I've added the `AccordionProvider` at the index.js level around the `App` but it still won't control `Collapsible` components that are rendered within another `Collapsible` component - I'll give `Redux` a try next

Comment: Apologies – I misunderstood your issue. There was a little extra code required to support `Collapsible` within `Collapsible` – see [updated sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-breeze-k3se4y), does that address the problem?

Comment: Perfect! Works just as intended, thank you. Now begins the fun task of trying to understand it fully so I can replicate it from scratch in other scenarios :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Redux`.

1. When you render you accordions give them a specific id and save it in the store.
2. Create a slice `openAllAccordions` that loop throw IDs and set the accordion belongs to that id to open=true
3. Create a slice `closeAllAccordions` that loop throw IDs and set the accordion belongs to that id to open=false